# SUM a column of cells based on check box

Tags: excel, function

I have a column of cells that I'm trying to sum based on whether or not a check box is checked. If the check box is not checked or FALSE the column would return the SUM, if the check box is checked or TRUE the cell would not return a SUM and just display "0".

Comment: Sounds like a nice project.  Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox can be linked to a cell which would contain the value of TRUE or FALSE:

```
=IF(B1,0,SUM(A2:A200))
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to enter FALSE as the value. This works!